# Writing an "if" function based on more than 2 conditions

Tags: excel, formulas

I'm trying to write a formula to do the following:

I have absolute values in `K37`, `N6`, `C4` and `C12`.

If `K37` is greater than `N6`, then the output is `(N6-C4)*C12`.

If `K37` is less than `N6` but greater than `C4`, the output is `(K37-C4)*C12`.

If `K37` is less than `C4`, then the output is `0`.

Comment: Please clean up your formula.  It is currently incomplete for the last two conditions.

Comment: What does `if a1c1` mean?  Also, what does `if a1` mean?

Comment: As Tim tells there is a problem with your conditions. The first or the last one must be removed. Example, does "if a cat does exist call the dog, if the cat" makes sense ?

Comment: i cant get the forum to post my whole question. I have 3 cells with absolute values. i need the output based on a set of conditions. If a1 is greater than b1, i need the output to be a function of x1*y1. if a1 is less than b1 but a1 is greater than c1, i need the output to be a function of z1*aa1 and if a1 is less than c1, i need the output to be 0

Comment: Please, remove your last comment and reuse it as content for your question. Also, do not forget, if an answer is what you need, to check it as correct! See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Also SE's forum are not used to post questions.

Comment: let me get more specific. i have absolute values in k37, n6, c4 and c12. if k37 is greater than n6, then the output is (n6-c4)*c12. If k37 is less than n6 but greater than c4, the output is (k37-c4)*c12. if k37 is less than c4, then the output is 0. thanks for the help.

Comment: thank you very much. works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about doing

```
=IF(K37>N6, (N6-C4)*C12, IF(AND(K37<N6, K37>C4), (K37-C4)*C12, IF(K37<C4, 0, "NOT TREATED CASE")))
```

The corresponfing pseudo code may be

```
if K37>N6 then
    return (N6-C4)*C12
else (if K37<=N6)
    if K37<N6 and K37>C4 then
        return (K37-C4)*C12
    else (if not (K37<N6 and K37>C4) )
        if K37<C4 then
            return 0
        else
            return "not treated case in which one
                    possibly has, e.g. K37=C4 or K37=N6"
```